# Trying to Get Started with Bourbon/SASS (& How to Compile in Adobe Brackets)

Tags: css, sass, adobe-brackets, bourbon

Apologies for my daftness here, but trying to start a new design workflow and having a hard time wrapping my head around a few basic concepts.

I know that I want to join the party late and begin utilizing preprocessing in my development.  After a lot of deliberation, I've also decided that I want to use Bourbon/Neat as the basic framework (as opposed to Bootstrap, etc.).  Lastly, I've also decided to move over to Adobe Brackets after years of using Komodo Edit as my basic editor.

That said, I'm struggling to figure out how to get the damn thing to work.  I've installed the SASS plugin for Brackets, but how exactly do I get Bourbon installed, get to work and start compiling.  I've been reading articles, but feel like there's something about the process that I'm just not comprehending.  If anyone can lend some thoughtful advice, it would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do not bother with plugin, just follow framework guide (1. install it using ruby/node/whatever 2. run framework file watcher, it will compile sass css on save). 
If you want to stick with plugin, then explore author's repo, it contains an example.